# Customizing header of error_messages_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I'm trying to get a custom error message using error_messages_for. I'm using rails 3 and have downloaded and installed the plugin. 
In my view I have:

```
error_messages_for :model
```

Which works and gives me error messages. However I'm wanting to change the default

```
1 error prohibited this model from being saved
```

etc.

I've managed to change the attribute names using the local file:

```
en:
  activemodel:    
    attributes:
      model:
        dateOfBirth: 'Date of birth'
        etc
```

However when I try adding in:

```
activemodel:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one:    "{{model}} is not valid"
          other:  "There are {{count}} errors prohibiting this {{model}} from being saved"
        # The variable :count is also available
        body: "The following fields have problems:"
```

As suggested in [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-the-active-record-error_messages_for-helper) it doesn't change the header and I don't get the new error messages.

I've tried both activemodel and activerecord.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125512/how-to-change-3-errors-prohibited-this-foobar-from-being-saved-validation-messa

Comment: Perhaps, but that's only a static header message I can't do plurals etc. Plus I can't modify the "There were problems with the following fields". Also I shouldn't have to set this every time I include the helper. The Rails Guide suggests to (and I would think that it is better to) use locale

Comment: you shouldn't downvote duplicate questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is to do with the plugin that I'm using. [Dynamic Form](https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form) is not exactly the same as how rails 2.3.x handles errors. In that errors is not scoped under Active Record. Looking at the locale file that ships with this plugin:

```
en:
  errors:
    template:
      header:
        one:    "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
        other:  "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
      body: "There were problems with the following fields:"
```

If I edit this file, then it works. 
Shortly be looking at whether this can be integrated into the plugin so it works same as 2.3.x